# PostgreSQL join 2 tables and get all values even if 1 table is empty

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 table. Objects and properties. Properties table has properties of the object. But it is possible that the object does not have any properties. 
I would like to make a query so that I get all the objects that have properties(value in property column) and all the objects that dont have properties(in this case the property column will be empty)

EXAMPLE: Simplified query that gives the same result

```
SELECT 
row_number () OVER() AS id,
seire.id seire_id,
tegevus.arenguvajadus
FROM andmed seire
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tegevused tegevus ON  seire.id = tegevus.seire_id
WHERE tegevus.aktiivne = true
```

Data example:

andmed:

```
Id, Data

1 , ...
2, ...
```

tegevused

```
id, aktiivne, arenguvajadus, seire_id

1, true, something something, 1

1, true, something2 , 1
```

Expected result

```
  ID, Seire_id, arenguvajadus

    1, 1, something something

    2, 1, something2

    3, 2,
```

Comment: What is the problem? Seems like simple `LEFT JOIN` to me.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Nope, LEFT JOIN does not solve this. I still get the same result where i only get object that have properties. Probabli UNION would be solution. 1 SELECT for object with properties and another for whidout properties

Comment: if left join did not help - use `right outer join`

Comment: @VaoTsun Still nope

Comment: then I'd like to see the stucture, data sample, query and failing result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove that `LEFT JOINed` table from your `WHERE`. I assume `tegevused` is properties.

```
SELECT 
row_number () OVER() AS id,
seire.id seire_id,
tegevus.arenguvajadus
FROM andmed seire
LEFT OUTER JOIN tegevused tegevus ON  seire.id = tegevus.seire_id AND tegevus.aktiivne = true
```